# Is it possible to do Uri.parse(Arraylist<POJO>)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, uri, exoplayer

Here is a piece of code. I am pretty much trying to do Uri.parse(Arraylist) instead of string values

```
ArrayList<StepsModel> videoURL = new ArrayList<>();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
```

Comment: Do you want a single Uri or a collection of Uri's?

Comment: @Mathieu  I have removed my answer because because I posted wrongly here. sorry for it

Comment: As for your problem the only Uri#parse method uses a String as a parameter so I would recommend to do a loop through your whole videoURL collection and then parse each one in an Uri list to finally use them in your mediasource

Comment: @RajasekaranM no problem, I was kinda confused by it :D

Comment: I have a collection of URI's that I need to parse. I was able to solve the problem by looping through the list of videoURL's. Thank you